# Are CPU voltage and RAM voltage related? What are the mutual constraints?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, voltage

I was wondering if the maximum value of my CPU voltage range is a constraint on my RAM voltage.

An example:

My VID Voltage Range is 0.60V-1.35V and my memory modules are to operate at 1.5V.

Am I in trouble? Will the CPU max voltage lower being lower, be detrimental to the performance of my memory modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPU supply voltage doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: So one could use very high voltage memory modules on a motherboard which has a CPU with a 1.35V max voltage?

Comment: Absolutely not. The RAM voltage affects all kinds of things. It's the CPU voltage that doesn't matter. That the CPU has a 1.35V max has no effect on anything. That doesn't mean it will work properly with RAM that requires a higher voltage than the CPU specifications allow *for the RAM voltage*.

Comment: I get it. But for example, how do I know [this CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/64593/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-15M-Cache-2_30-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI) will accomodate otherwise  compatible 1.5V memory modules. In other terms, how do I know what my motherboard allow for RAM voltage?

Comment: You can check page 144 of the [spec sheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-v2-datasheet-vol-1.pdf). (1.28V to 1.45V for DDR3L, 1.42V to 1.57V for DDR3.)